# tvDatafeed.main:no data, please check the exchange and symbol

Tags: python

I am getting below occasionally while using tvDatafeed though the script is valid and works fine.
If I re-iterate the same script it works fine.

Error :

```
ERROR:tvDatafeed.main:Connection to remote host was lost.
ERROR:tvDatafeed.main:no data, please check the exchange and symbol
```